# My query only takes one of my point instead of all

Tags: sql, database, points

I've done a query to send points from a another table. 
But the problem is, it only takes one of the point row instead of adding every points from every rows.
Here is my script:

```
UPDATE Users 
     SET Users.Point = Billing.Point 
FROM PS_UserData.dbo.Users_Master Users INNER JOIN 
     PS_Website.dbo.Billing Billing 
     ON Users.UserUID = Billing.UserUID 
GROUP BY Billing.UserUID;
```

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc) that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not look valid in *any* database that I know of -- `GROUP BY` is not part of `UPDATE` syntax. I am guessing that you are using SQL Server.  If so, aggregate before joining:

```
UPDATE u 
     SET Point = b.total_Point 
FROM PS_UserData.dbo.Users_Master u INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT b.UserUID, SUM(b.Point) as total_point
      FROM PS_Website.dbo.Billing b 
      GROUP BY b.UserUID
     ) b
     ON u.UserUID = b.UserUID;
```

Comment: I actually love you! Thanks you very much :D